# Trick Facebook into believing I'm in a different location

Tags: facebook, geolocation

I'm trying to convince the Facebook website that I'm writing from a different place. Originally, because I'd like to fully understand the ways in which I'm being spied upon. But by now, after several hours of trying, it has also become a matter of principle to me...

## What I don't mean:

I am *not* talking about the regular "Check In" function, where you click the pin and choose a location from the list of suggestions when writing a post. That one is working fine, and I know I can check in to any place in the world, even though I'm not really currently there.

## What I do mean:

I mean the place that Facebook inserts there *automatically*, as seen in these pictures:

[image]

[image]

## Things I have tried / found out so far:

- **WiFi/mobile network:** It has nothing to do with either of them. I'm trying this on a desktop PC that does't even have a WiFi adapter. The connection is Ethernet only.
- **IP:** Facebook does not seem to use my public IP for this, because then it would have to be some 80-100 km away from me, where my provider's next server is. Also, I tried a proxy in another country, and it still showed my real town.

  *However*, It did recognize me logging in from a different place, as can be seen see in my currently active sessions:

  [image]
- **Windows:** Windows 10 location service is completely disabled.
- **Browser:** Facebook is not asking my Firefox for the location (otherwise I would see that "target" icon in the address bar and also have to allow it manually first). To be extra-sure, I explicitly disabled location permission for the Facebook website in Firefox.
- **Cookies/cache:** I logged out several times, cleaning cookies and cache, then logged back in. Nothing.
- **Firefox addon:** I installed [Location Guard](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/location-guard/), set it to a fake place, and it seems to be working (tested [here](http://noc.to/geoloc) and [here](http://html5demos.com/geo)). Still no change on Facebook.
- **Console:** I used the Firefox console (network tab) to see if I could find any location-related requests, but didn't find any. (However, many requests don't use plaintext, but are encoded in some way, so I don't really understand all of them.)
- **Near devices:** I also tried logging out of *all* other devices, also clearing their cookies and cache, and ended all active sessions from Facebook's "Security" tab.
- **Hometown/current city:** Facebook is not taking the city from my profile either. I changed hometown and current residence to random places, but nothing changed.
- **Google account:** Just to be sure, I also changed my "home" in Google Maps, although Facebook doesn't seem to rely on a Google API for this. (Also, when I allow Google to find me, it is only able to locate my ISP's server 80-100 km away from me, as mentioned above.)

I'm really running out of ideas. What other possibilities could there be?

Comment: FB will learn and remember from previous session, have you tried with new local account, new browser and from a VPN?

Comment: "Facebook uses information from multiple sources such as current city from profile, IP address, data from mobile devices and **aggregated information about the location of friends.**" from https://www.facebook.com/business/help/133609753380850

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keeping websites from knowing where I live](http://superuser.com/questions/115536/keeping-websites-from-knowing-where-i-live)